# Inequality involving probability of $n$ intersecting events

Tags: probability

Is it always true that $ P(\cap^n_{i=1} A_i) \leq P(\cap^{n-1}_{i=1} A_i)$ for any set of n events.

I think it is true. If the new event is a superset of the other n events, the probability is the same. Otherwise, it makes it less probable that another event occurs concurrently with the previous n-1 events. Also it would be good if someone could point me to some resources that might help me prove this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: recall that if $A,B$ are two events with $A\subset B$, then $\mathbb{P}(A)\leq \mathbb{P}(B)$, because $\mathbb{P}(B)=\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B\setminus A)$.

In your question, $\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i=(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i)\cap A_n\subset \bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i$, hence
$$ \mathbb{P}\Big(\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i\Big)\leq \mathbb{P}\Big(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i\Big) $$

Answer (score 1):

In general if $A\subseteq B$ , (where A and B are events) we have that $P(A)\leq P(B)$ since $P(B)=P(A)+P(B\setminus A)$. Since $\cap^n_{i=1} A_i\subseteq \cap^{n-1}_{i=1} A_i$, the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as it is always true that 
$$
\cap_{i=1}^{n} A_{i} \subset \cap_{i=1}^{n-1} A_{i}.
$$